# Alexa not detecting dates with slot AMAZON.DATE if spoken like December thirty first(one) 2013

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am building a skill where user is required say his date of birth.

some examples are what he could say for this

```
 - September twenty fifth nineteen eighty seven 
 - Fourth January nineteen ninety
 - Four January two thousand four
 - Four January two zero zero four
 - March Fifteen two thousand one
```

I have used AMAZON.DATE for the slots. Alexa is failing to resolve the date in-fact, it fails to resolve the intent it self and its response is always

```
"I don't know that one"
```

below are the sample utterances I have used for this intent

```
DateOfBirth my date of birth is {dob}
DateOfBirth {dob} is my date of Birth 
DateOfBirth {dob} is my birth date 
DateOfBirth birth date is {dob} 
DateOfBirth it is {dob}
DateOfBirth {dob}
```

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

According to alexa documentation the type slot AMAZON.date accept only dates on or after the current date.So all your examples here will not work. for the full documentation please visit [this url](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/built-in-intent-ref/slot-type-reference#date)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the Date slot that is the problem.  I have a skill that uses a date slot and when I put in a date that you mentioned, it returns correctly.  For example:

> Ask about exhibitions on **September twenty fifth nineteen eighty seven**

```
{
  "session": {
    "sessionId": "SessionId.removed",
    "application": {
    "applicationId": "amzn1.removed"
},
  "attributes": {},
  "user": {
    "userId": "removed"
},
  "new": true
},
  "request": {
  "type": "IntentRequest",
  "requestId": "EdwRequestId.removed",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "timestamp": "2017-06-19T18:14:00Z",
  "intent": {
    "name": "ExhibitionsIntent",
    "slots": {
      "Date": {
        "name": "Date",
        "value": "1987-09-25"
    }
  }
}
},
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

And here is the Intent in the Interaction Model:

```
ExhibitionsIntent exhibitions {Date}

{
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "Date",
      "type": "AMAZON.DATE"
    }
  ],
  "intent": "ExhibitionsIntent"
},
```